# Using tenorflow and python-not finding modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When running my python code, i get the following error,

```
File "run_webcam.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tf_pose.estimator import TfPoseEstimator
  File __init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tf_pose.runner import infer, Estimator, get_estimator
  File runner.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tf_pose import eval
  File eval.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tf_pose.networks import model_wh, get_graph_path
  File networks.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tf_pose.network_mobilenet import MobilenetNetwork
  File network_mobilenet.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tf_pose import network_base
  File network_base.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I think that  i need to import the dependencies differently as i am using tensorflow 2.0.0 and python 3.7.3.

how do i for example change the slim import to work correctly?

Comment: tf2.0 has get did of contrib module.

Comment: i have downgraded to tf1.4.1 and I now get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following commands to solve this issue:

conda create -n tfpose python=3.6 pip

conda activate tfpose

pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install tensorflow

conda install tensorflow

Now execute your python code.